# Can I use MP3 format for android 2.2 (API 8)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want use MP3 format for my application in android 2.2 (API 8) and higher. But If I use MP3 format will the MP3 file run properly in android 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. It should run properly, according to the supported media formats from the [android developer guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your expectation is to play a `MP3` file through a player, you can do so from `Android 2.2`. In this case, you should be employing the `MediaPlayer` object to do so.

If you wish to have a standalone decoder i.e. `MP3 decoder`, then it is possible only from `JellyBean` i.e. `Android 4.1`, where a `MediaCodec` can be used for standalone `MP3` decoding.